# How to test a mega menu

Tags: usability-testing, information-architecture, mega-menu

I've been asked to test a mega menu. I can't use a tree test because that tests the information architecture and I'm looking for a way to specifically test the layout and organisation of the mega menu.

Has any one got any guidance for this?

Answer (score 1):

If you are unsure about the organization of the (mega) menu, a card sorting exercise could be fit. Or just do the card sorting with those items you are more unsure about.
For the layout of the menu, I would set up a series of quick tests to understand if the user can "read" the menu:

- First level navigation
- Second level navigation
- Additional info you provide on the mega menu

These would be simple tasks to find information within the website, through the menu.

In a mega menu, the programming could make the difference. I mean, how the frontend is developed is something that should be tested, as slight pointer movements/reactions and how the frontend reacts to it can make the difference between a good and a bad experience. So, I would suggest of course testing before developing, but also consider specific tests after development is done.

Answer (score 0):

You can test both aspects separately.

1. Use a tree test for the information architecture
2. Use simple scenario within usability testing to test the interaction  of the menu

I don't see anything more to this than a combination of those two aspects.

Comment: that's just a rewording of my question

Comment: No, it is not. Thanks for the downvote though.
I stand by the answer. You need to do both in order to test it. Maybe try to rephrase your question if you feel you need to downvote all answers.

Answer (score 0):

You could do an information retrieval task.  By that I mean select a few items from the mega menu for the users to find and you could record time, error rate, etc.  You could do that as part of a larger task (like the simple scenario that the previous poster mentioned).

Comment: Not sure why this is being downvoted. Watching task completion times for key menu items seems like a good method here.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a click test or chalk test if you want to test the visual layout and organization of the mega menu. You could measure the time taken to click, if you have all the options on the menu.

If you just have the broad categories, you could ask testers where they would click to find x.